# Hyper V - How do you tell (using Powershell) when an OS is fully spun up and ready after a VM is started?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu VM that I start up using Powershell. I can get the "state" property of the VM and see it is "running" but that is just the VM. That is NOT when the OS is fully spun up and available to use which can take minutes for some OSs. Is there a way (using powershell) to know when an OS is fully running and ready to be accessed after the VM is started?

Comment: If you have _integration services_ enabled for the VM, then [heartbeat service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/integration-services#hyper-v-heartbeat-service) is supposed to give this information. Contrary to the docs, for my test VM the `Status` property always reports as `Operating normally`, even if the VM is switched off. There is a `Heartbeat` property which seems to fit the purpose. For my test VM it reports `OkApplicationsUnknown` when the OS is spun up.

Comment: Couldn't find a documentation for the `Heartbeat` property.  To see all possible values, enter `[Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMHeartbeatStatus].GetEnumValues()`.

Comment: I have tested this on several different Linux OSs and I see some works but some like Fedora always shows Not Connected.  I guess I could just put some smarts in there where if it works, then move on and it if doesn't, move on after a time out.